# BadRequestException: Unable to update route. Authorizer type is invalid or null when authorization_type NONE

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway

I have an aws http apigatewayv2 module.

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "this" {
  for_each             = var.routes_configuration
  api_id               = aws_apigatewayv2_api.this.id
  route_key            = "${each.value.http_method} /${each.value.route}"
  target               = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.this[each.key].id}"
  authorization_type   = each.value.auth_type
  authorizer_id        = aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.this.id
  authorization_scopes = each.value.auth_type == "JWT" ? ["${local.api-resource-server}/${each.value.route}"] : null
}
```

For certain routes, I need authorization_type to be NONE, so that the route is public.
Given the the situation that I already created the route with a "JWT" authorization_type, when I switch to "NONE" authorization type everything is going well but when another terraform apply is run I have the following exception : `updating API Gateway v2 route (*****): BadRequestException: Unable to update route. Authorizer type is invalid or null.`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that I was providing an `authorizer_id` with an authorization_type "NONE".
In my case the authorization_type is either "JWT" or "NONE", hence the authorization_type is not "JWT", the authorizer_id should be null.

From
`authorizer_id        = aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.this.id`
to
`authorizer_id        = each.value.auth_type == "JWT" ? aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.this.id : null`

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "this" {
  for_each             = var.routes_configuration
  api_id               = aws_apigatewayv2_api.this.id
  route_key            = "${each.value.http_method} /${each.value.route}"
  target               = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.this[each.key].id}"
  authorization_type   = each.value.auth_type
  authorizer_id        = each.value.auth_type == "JWT" ? aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.this.id : null #CHANGED 
  authorization_scopes = each.value.auth_type == "JWT" ? ["${local.api-resource-server}/${each.value.route}"] : null
}
```